# dapr uninstall does not clean up all the containers that it created

Tags: dapr

On my Windows machine, I successfully initialized dapr as explained [here](https://docs.dapr.io/getting-started/install-dapr-selfhost/#step-2-run-the-init-cli-command).

But upon uninstalling it, two docker containers continue to run.

[image: Docker container after uninstalling dapr]

Am I missing something? What should I do to completely clean that up? Do I have to manually stop those two containers?

Answer (score 2):

This is mentioned on their dapr cli github page.
https://github.com/dapr/cli
and is in case you use redis or anything else for other purposes.

To remove all, use:
dapr uninstall --all

Answer (score 1):

You can manually stop these 2 containers by running command `docker stop the-container-id`. In this case, it would be `docker stop 492fd54a93ca`, `docker stop c852e328d489`. Given that the 2 running containers are the ones you want to remove, you could also use docker stop `docker ps -aq`. Hope it helps.